# Woocommerce: Turn off min/max validation when bundled item is added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There's a conflict between the Woocommerce Min/Max Quantities Extension and the Bundled Items Extension. I've spoken to Woo support and they say there's no way to turn off min/max validation on individual items that are part of a bundled item.

When a bundled item is added to the cart that contains items with min/max limits it throws an error that the shopper needs to add more of the individual items.

I'm trying to turn off min/max validation on individual items when they are part of a bundled item that is added to cart.

Important note: I need to still track the inventory of the individual items.

I realize the dangers of editing a plugin directly as changes will be lost on update but I'm willing to risk that to get this to work. (I know you can make a copy of the plugin and that might be what I do.)

Specifically I've been trying to adapt a compatibility patch made for Composite items and make it work for Bundled items.

I found this in their changelog:

```
2015-11-03 - version 2.3.9
* Fix - Variation level category exclude option not working.
* New - Compatibility with Composite Products plugin to disable min/max logic when product is of type composite.
```

And found reference to composite item compatibility in four places in the plugin.  Here's an example of a function that has code that checks for composite products and code I added to mimic it (relevant code has **'s for emphasis)

```
    public function check_rules( $product, $quantity, $minimum_quantity, $maximum_quantity, $group_of_quantity ) {
        //**************************
        // composite products plugin compatibility 
        if ( $this->addons->is_composite_product( $product->id ) ) {
            return;
        }
        //**************************

        //**************************
        //This is what I added:
        // bundled products plugin compat
        if ( $this->addons->wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item( $product->id ) ) {
            return;
        }
        //**************************
        if ( $minimum_quantity > 0 && $quantity < $minimum_quantity ) {

            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( 'The minimum allowed quantity for %s is %s - please increase the quantity in your cart.', 'woocommerce-min-max-quantities' ), $product->get_title(), $minimum_quantity ) );

        } elseif ( $maximum_quantity > 0 && $quantity > $maximum_quantity ) {

            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( 'The maximum allowed quantity for %s is %s - please decrease the quantity in your cart.', 'woocommerce-min-max-quantities' ), $product->get_title(), $maximum_quantity ) );

        }

        if ( $group_of_quantity > 0 && ( $quantity % $group_of_quantity ) ) {

            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( '%s must be bought in groups of %d. Please add or decrease another %d to continue.', 'woocommerce-min-max-quantities' ), $product->get_title(), $group_of_quantity, $group_of_quantity - ( $quantity % $group_of_quantity ) ) );

        }
    }
```

I found the same chunk of code checking for composite items in functions update_quantity_args(), add_to_cart(). So I added my adaptation there too.

My code throws the error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Min_Max_Quantities_Addons::wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item() in /.../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-min-max-quantities/min-max-quantities.php on line 580**

I tried updating code from `wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item()` to `WC_Min_Max_Quantities_Addons::wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item()` but that caused a fatal error.

So two questions: Is there an easier way to go about this I'm not seeing?  And if not how can I correctly adapt that composite item patch for bundled items?

Any help is much appreciated!

## Update:

I've added a function called `is_bundled_product()` based on the `is_composite_product()` function in class-wc-min-max-quantities-addons.php based on inarilo's advice:

```
//original is is_composite_product() function:
public function is_composite_product( $product_id ) {
        if ( empty( $product_id ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( 'composite' === $product->product_type ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

//my function based on composite function:
    public function is_bundled_product( $product_id ) {
        if ( empty( $product_id ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( 'bundle' === $product->product_type ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This update removed all the error messages but it still shows the user a warning that they need to add more of the individual items to meet min/max requirements so the it still doesn't remove that validation to allow purchase.

## Update

I also tried excluding the items in the bundle from order rules but it still throws the warning in the cart.

see picture: [excluding individual items](https://i.gyazo.com/96faf9e92487f9dee3125333e49266ae.png/)

Comment: Try using unchecked "Manage Stoke" on Product page. http://prntscr.com/f4hj6a

Comment: On the bundled item product page or individual item? I have to manage stock on the individual items

Comment: You could suggest to the plugin authors some sort of filter at the beginning of the `check_rules()` method.... so `if ( 'composite' === $product->product_type || apply_filters( 'wc_min_max_quantities_skip_rules', false, $product ) { return true; }`  Then you could filter that from your own plugin.

Comment: have you checked what the actual value of `product_type` is? also, where did you get the name of the function you were using originally? does that function exist?

Comment: Here's where I found the original wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item() function: [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/#wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item)

Comment: I added this to check if it's getting  a product type and it printed 'bundle' so it is seeing that the product is a bundle:

`//get product object`
                    `$product = wc_get_product( $product->id );`
`//echo product type - which echos 'bundle' to screen`
  `echo $product->product_type;`

Comment: And if you use `==` instead?

Comment: or http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productis_type/

Comment: You can also try calling `wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item`, in which case you can replace the last 5 lines with `return wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item($product_id);`

Answer (score 1):

`$this->addons->wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item( $product->id )` throwing this error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Min_Max_Quantities_Addons::wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item() in /.../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-min-max-quantities/min-max-quantities.php on line 580**

means that the `addons` property you are referencing, which is an instance of the class `WC_Min_Max_Quantities_Addons` has no method called `wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item`.

Either you are referencing it the wrong way or you need to find the above class definition, copy the `is_composite_product` method and modify it as per your need to create the `wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item` method.

Comment: I added a function called is_bundled_product() to the class-min-max-quantities-addons.php based off of the is_composite_product() function. This removed the errors so thank you! The cart is still showing warnings to add stock of individual items though so I'm not sure what I'm missing.